# Why do any of the ordered characters in a string appear to be a part of a list which is equivalent to that string?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

My book says -

> Strings and lists are actually similar, if you consider a string to be a “list” of single text characters.

Suppose that I have a string namely 
`name=Zophie`.

Now this string should have some resemblance with a list. So I type in another code that would tell me what should the items of that list be. The code goes like -

`for i in name:
  print(‘* * * ‘ + i + ‘ * * *')`

The output is:

`* * * Z * * *
* * * o * * *
* * * p * * *
* * * h * * *
* * * i * * *
* * * e * * *`

This clearly shows that the list items of `name` are Z,o,p,h,i,e.

Now if I try to check wether the list has an item `’Zop'` by using:

`Zop in name`

It returns True! That is, Python says that Zophie contains an item namely `’Zop’` but when I tried to list all the items using the for command, `Zop` didn’t show up.

What’s happening here?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "but when I tried to list all the items using the for command, Zop didn’t show up."

Comment: @idjaw , `for i in name:
  print(‘* * * ‘ + I + ‘ * * *’)` . 

This should return all the items in the list and the items that were displayed on the screen were Z,o,p,h,i,e. ‘Zop’ was not there. Now if I try `Zop in name` , it should return False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different `in`s:

- `for i in name`: The word `in` is part of the [`for`-loop syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).
  The statement iterates over the elements of the iterable `name`.
  If `name` is a string, then it iterates over the characters of the string.
- `'Zop' in name`: The word `in` is a comparison operator. From the documentation, [5.9.1 Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

  > For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if `x` is a substring of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

Comment: Take another example: 
`spam=[‘asd’,’qwe’,’zxc’,’fgh’]` . Here (‘asd’, ‘qwe’ ) looks like a substring to me ( correct me if I am wrong ). Now if you type in ` ( ‘asd’,’qwe’) in spam ` in the IDLE, you again get `False` despite of that fact that `( ‘asd’,’qwe’)` is a substring of spam!?

Comment: @AaryanDewan `spam` is *not* a string but a list. In this case, `in` tests membership. The tuple `('asd', 'qwe')` is *not* a member of `spam`. For example, it is a member of `[('asd', 'qwe'), 42, True]`.

Comment: Now I get it! Could you please tell me what do you mean by membership? Does it mean that it checks wether one string is a part of a list or not?

Comment: @AaryanDewan It checks, whether an element (that can be a string, number, boolean value, list, tuple, ..., an object of any type) belongs to a list, set, ... It is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`, see the cited [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations).

Comment: Thanks a lot Heiko!

Answer (score 2):

Any Python class is free to define various operations however it likes. Strings happen to implement the sequence protocol  (meaning that iteration and `[i]` item access behave the same as lists), but also implement `__contains__`, which is responsible for `x in y` checks, to look for *substrings* rather than just single characters.

It is *common* for `x in y` membership testing to mean "x will appear if you print all the elements of y", but there's no rule saying that that *has* to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the section on [Membership test detail](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), which is relevant to the `in` keyword. Paraphrasing from there,

> For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if x is a
>   substring of y. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings
>   are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

Although, I strongly suggest that elegant use of the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module can be picked over a membership test for a substring.